# Search API Attachments Facet returning part words

Tags: search

I’m using these modules for the search :  Search API attachments; Search API Attachments Field Collections; Solr search; Search Facets

One of the Fields I’m searching is from attachments and I’m using type ‘Fulltext’ .

Then when setting up a Facet for this field it return a whole heap of the most common keywords.  The only problem being that in some cases it's returning part words.  For example in the attachments the words 'manage' 'management' 'manager' would exist, and the Facet is returning 'manag' as my keyword.  Has anyone else come across this; and do you know how I can make it so that only whole words are returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before I go into to how I solved this; its worth repeating what feed back of this from our hosts. 
'This will happen if you attempt to create a facet for a Solr field of type "text" (which might be the case here), because Solr stems and further processes all words before storing them on the index. There is no direct way to get around this.

Also, faceting on text is not really recommended:

UX-wise, searchers get too much noise, because words come from all over the place--your top facets could be just common words like 'the', 'with', 'you', 'they', etc.

Performance-wise, calculating the facets to show for large fields takes a long time. '

I have got things looking like how I want them though and that was to use 'Facet API BONUS' module.

1. Install and Enable Module
2. Configuration > Search and metadata > Exclude specified items > Add to Exclude items

> Save Configuration

You only get a limited amount of words with this module .  If needed this can be changed by extending the Form in

Facetapi>filter_exclude_specified_items .
class FacetapiFilterExcludeItems::settingsForm

And adding a '#maxlength'

This is a pretty good blog on adding how to other extended functionality changes to the Facet API module  http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/apachesolr-and-facetapi